Collectives Update: WSO2
The WSO2 Collective will be decommissioned on July 17. Questions and answers that were part of the Collective will not be affected, apart from the removal of collective-specific markup. All published articles will remain accessible via https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/articles and will be editable by the Stack Overflow community. For technical details about the decommissioning, visit this Help Center article.
Stack Overflow is grateful to the team at WSO2 for helping explore, in this beta stage, how a Collective can help members learn and share knowledge about WSO2 technology to build faster and better.
If you’ve been a member of the WSO2 Collective, what did you find valuable about the experience?

Would you be able to share some details on why the decision to decommission this Collective was made (besides end of sponsorship)?
In case of other Collectives (e.g. Google Cloud) you've only "transferred" the ownership to the community.

Probably because no one ever figured out what WSO2 stands for...

@TylerH ... or could be the low quality of Q&A

There needs to be a critical mass of question/answer creation, creation of other content such as articles or collections, and community engagement in order for the subcommunity to thrive. In this case, that just isn't quite there — not to the degree that it is for the Google Cloud Collective or Microsoft Azure Collective, which remained after the sponsorships ended. There are certainly community members who are active in WSO2 tags and are making excellent contributions. We hope that some will offer their perspectives here.

@TylerH I was very amused by your comment in 2022, and I am just as amused by this one today :)
